# Railsで画像ファイルをJavascriptを使って操作したい

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

アセットパイプラインを使用する前提で、

app/assets/images/1.jpg

に画像ファイルを配置した場合、これをJavascriptで操作する際のパスの指定の仕方がわかりません。

例えば、簡単なjQueryでjsファイル（ないしはerbファイル内のscriptタグ）内で

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("div").css("background-image","url(1.png)");
});
```

としても、動きません。

どなたか、教えていただけますでしょうか？

実際のコードは別なので、単にcssファイルでパス指定する方法ではなく、あくまでもjs内でどうパス指定するかを、教えていただけるとありがたいです。

Comment: ちなみに、Rails 5を使用しています。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/96599

Answer (score 1):

`erb`であれば下記の方法で参照できるはずです。

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("div").css("background-image","url(<%= asset_path 'image.png' %>)");
});
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。できました。jsファイル内で記述する方法も分かれば教えていただけると助かります。

Comment: 解決したようでよかったです。ただ、複数サイトに質問を投げる場合はその旨を記載して、他のサイトで回答がついた場合にその回答についても情報共有として元の質問に追記してください。またどのように対応するかはサイトによって違いますので、それぞれのサイトの利用規則を参考にしてください。今回の件ですと既にTeratailでついている回答に該当の記述への参照があります。

Comment: 失礼しました。こちらへの反映を失念しておりました。jsファイルであったとしても、JavaScriptの拡張子を.js.erbのようにすれば、JavaScript中にERBを埋め込め、image_pathやasset_pathが使えるとの回答を、teratailでいただいておりました。ご指摘ありがとうございます。